# How to change redirect_uri for Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I've got Azure ServiceFabric web-app (AspNetCore 3) hosted over reverse proxy (NGinx). The app use AzureAD (in company) authentication. I've Registered App for the AD and setup Redirect Urls. After publishing the APP and configuring DNS and reverse proxy I tried to authorize to my app but failed with error

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '...-...-...-...-...'.
```

I snifed the request and found that it redirects to the internal IP but not domain name

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/aeb55839-c47b-4fea-8d95-912f673fa7ac/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=.....&redirect_uri=`**http%3A%2F%2F10.2.0.5%3A44321%2Fsignin-oidc**`...`

It seems that I've looked everywhere but I cannot stil found where I can specify redirect url manually (only CallbackPath).
Does anyone solve the issue?

#### Update 1.

Add screenshot from Azure Portal
[image]

#### Update 2

Mannually add http://10.2.0.5:44321/signin-oidc to the Redirect Url, get a new exception
`AADSTS500117: The reply uri specified in the request isn't using a secure scheme.`
I wonder whether I have to make my ASF cluster secured to allow AD Authorization? It seems to me strange due to I want to secure traffic to reverse proxy only.

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur when there is a mismatch of redirect URI being sent in the request to AAD while fetching the token and the one registered with the Application Registration Object in AAD portal.

In App Registration blade of AAD and look for the redirect URI section present under "Authentication" section of the registered application and update the redirection
URL. Please refer to the screenshot below:
[image]

**update:-**
The Reply url you are using in your code is `http://10.2.0.5:44321/signin-oidc` which is different from reply url defined in Azure AD i.e., `https://dev-adm.project-llc.ru/signin-oidc`. Please update the reply url in code or in AAD.

Comment: I've double checked it already and it has domain name. Update topic with screenshot

Comment: The Reply url you are using in your code is `http://10.2.0.5:44321/signin-oidc` which is different from reply url defined in Azure AD i.e., `https://dev-adm.project-llc.ru/signin-oidc`.

Comment: As i described above I cannot find how can I specify ReplyUrl from code - It generated automatically and I want to change its behaviour to specify doman.

Comment: Hi @shaddow,We have given answer based on  your first question which is to update reply url in AAD.since your scenario is changed  to update in code please raise a new question stack overflow question with all details of implementation of code instead of updating current question, and we definitely help you with the solution.