# How to enable HTTP endpoints for Redirect Url in AzureAD?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I've got Azure ServiceFabric web-app (AspNetCore 3) hosted over reverse proxy (NGinx). The app use AzureAD (in company) authentication. I've Registered App for the AD and setup Redirect Urls mannually in manifest. After publishing the APP and configuring DNS and reverse proxy I tried to authorize to my app but failed with `AADSTS500117: The reply uri specified in the request isn't using a secure scheme.`

**Is it possible to configure client to allow http redirects?**

P.S. As I know Identity Server allows it by configuring DiscoveryPolicy.

P.P.S. You can find more information in my origianl question (see. [How to change redirect_uri for Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169170))

Comment: Why can't you use a secure scheme? And no, there is no way to allow it except for localhost.

Comment: Also, looking at your other question, this isn't really going to help you. If the user accessed the app on the external URL, you don't want to have them redirected to the internal endpoint (especially since they very likely won't have local network access). Since you already have an outside-facing HTTPS URL, what you need is for your app's code to use the external hostname when building the redirect URL, instead of changing the Azure AD app registration configuration.

Comment: @juunas, firstly it is redundand to transfer data within isolated network, secondary, I use Kestrel and it is recommended to handle HTTPS on reverse proxy only.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret, you absolutely right, I need to use the external hostname but I cannot find a way haw can I build it manually.

Comment: You mean the connection between user browser and the app is isolated? The redirect URI is used by the user's machine to access the app.

Comment: From browser to load balancer (LB) it is HTTPS, from LB to Azure ServiceFabric (ASF) it is HTTP due to LB and  ASF are internal resources (private network). It seems to to me redundand to have a HTTPS for internal network.

Answer (score 0):

### What happens?

when you deploy web apps with a reverse proxy, as is, for instance the case with App Services as Linux containers, your application will be called on an HTTP address, whereas its registered redirect URI in the app registration will be HTTPS.

This means that when a user browses to the web app, they will be redirected to login.microsoftonline.com as expected, but with `redirect_uri=http://<your app service name>.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc` instead of `redirect_uri=https://<your app service name>.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc.`

### How to fix it?

In order to get the right result, the guidance from the ASP.NET Core team for working with proxies is in [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer). You should address the issue centrally by using `UseForwardedHeaders` to fix the request fields, like scheme.

The container scenario should have been addressed by default in .NET Core 3.0. See Forwarded Headers Middleware Updates in .NET Core 3.0 preview 6. If there are issues with this for you, please contact the ASP .NET Core team https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore, as they will be the right team to assist with this.